# Rad Grid prerender event Issue

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

Can anyone tell me the things happening in this section? Why is it making items invisible?

```
protected void rgStateTax_PreRender( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        if( rgStateTax.MasterTableView.IsItemInserted )
        {
            foreach( GridItem item in rgStateTax.Items )
            {
                item.Visible = false;
            }
        }

        if( rgStateTax.EditItems.Count > 0 )
        {
            foreach( GridDataItem item in rgStateTax.Items )
            {
                if( item != rgStateTax.EditItems[0] )
                {
                    item.Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

here rgStateTax is rad grid and PreRender is the event before the page is actually displayed on the screen, right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, PreRender is called before the control is rendered for the page.

This snippet of code is simply looping through almost every item in the grid and making it invisible.

`if( rgStateTax.MasterTableView.IsItemInserted )` This checks if an item has been inserted into the grid.

`foreach( GridItem item in rgStateTax.Items )` This loops through every item in the radgrid.

`item.Visible = false;` This sets each item to be invisible.

As for the next part:

`if( rgStateTax.EditItems.Count > 0 )`
This checks if there are any grid items in edit mode.

`foreach( GridDataItem item in rgStateTax.Items )` This loops through every item in the radgrid (regardless if each item is in edit mode or not).

`if( item != rgStateTax.EditItems[0] )` This checks if the current item is not the first item in edit mode (so we enter this for all but one item.

`item.Visible = false;` This sets each item to be invisible.

And that's what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted

```
    if(!item.Edit){item.Visible = false;}
```